# Yii2 FileInput - File not saved into the server

Tags: php, yii2

[image: screenshot]

i am using Yii2 and Kartik's FileInput extension. and I am having issues with it saving to the directory. I am using the yii-advanced template, and generate the CRUD codes using gii. Currently editing it as I go.

When I save it it refused to save and show the "Please upload a file" message.

Files that will be saved with be .doc and .pdf mostly.

If I set the 'skipOnEmpty = True' in the model, it will save the form but not the file.

Datatype on my mysql table is set to VARCHAR because I want to save its path only.

I followed this guide - http://webtips.krajee.com/upload-file-yii-2-using-fileinput-widget/

Here is my model;

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;

class FormMovement extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{

    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'form_movement';
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['fm_date_received', 'fm_form_name', 'fm_from', 'fm_ptj'], 'required'],
            [['form_id'], 'integer'],
            [['fm_date_received', 'fm_date_action1', 'fm_date_action2'], 'safe'],
            [['fm_form_name', 'fm_note'], 'string', 'max' => 500],
            [['fm_from', 'fm_ptj', 'fm_action1', 'fm_action2'], 'string', 'max' => 100],
            [['fm_upload'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions'=>'jpg,pdf,png,doc,docx,xls,xlsx'],
        ];
    }

}
```

Then here is my controller(i included only the upload function, but it is the rest with the generated codes(CRUD actions),

```
<?php

namespace frontend\controllers;

use Yii;
use app\models\FormMovement;
use app\models\SearchFormMovement;
//use app\models\FormType;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;

class FormMovementController extends Controller
{
public function actionUpload()
{
    $model = new FormMovement;
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'fm_upload');

        // store the source file name
        $model->fm_upload = $file->name;
        $ext = end((explode(".", $file->name)));

        $model->fm_upload = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString().".{$ext}";

        $path = Yii::$app->params['uploadPath'] . $model->fm_upload;;

        if($model->save()){
            $file->saveAs($path);
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id'=>$model->_id]);
        } else {
            // error in saving model
        }
    }
    return $this->render('create', [
        'model'=>$model,
    ]);
}
}
```

and this is my view, also the same like Controller. Codes are only the upload part.

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use kartik\date\DatePicker;
//use app\models\FormMovement;
use app\models\FormType;
use yii\bootstrap\ActiveField;
use kartik\form\ActiveForm;
use kartik\file\FileInput;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\models\FormMovement */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
?>

<div class="form-movement-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([![\[][1]][1]
        'type' => ActiveForm::TYPE_HORIZONTAL,
        'formConfig' => ['labelSpan' => 3, 'deviceSize' => ActiveForm::SIZE_SMALL], 
        'options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']
    ]); ?>
<div class="form-group kv-fieldset-inline">
        <?= Html::activeLabel($model, 'fm_upload', [
                'label'=>'MUAT NAIK FAIL',
                'class'=>'col-sm-1 control-label'
            ]) ?>

        <div class="col-sm-8">
        <?= $form->field($model, 'fm_upload',[
                    'showLabels'=>false
                ])->widget(FileInput::classname(), [
                'options' => ['accept' => 'image/*'],
                'pluginOptions'=>['allowedFileExtensions'=>['jpg','pdf','png','doc','docx','xls','xlsx']
        ]]) ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>
```

Hope I have provided enough info. Appreciate any help.

EDIT: Here is what the logs looks like, I think its the validation issue but I can't really figure out which one is causing it, the model or the controller.

[image: SO2]

Comment: Throws any errors, while saving?

Comment: @InsaneSkull no errors, my guess is that is it not saving at all. see my edited post for logs screenshot.

Comment: see browser console for more info about validation error.

Comment: @InsaneSkull you mean as Inspect Element in Chrome? There's nothing to see in the log there. Just "Navigated to http://localhost/adminsys/form-movement/create" in there.

If in yii log, I am not sure where to look for that browser console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the path is correct and doesn't lack of / for example.

Define your path:

```
Yii::$app->params['uploadPath'] = Yii::getAlias("@frontend") . '/web/uploads/';
```

Then, *$model->fm_upload* doesn't have the value until you save it:

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'fm_upload');

        // store the source file name
        $ext = end((explode(".", $file->name)));

        $new_name = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString().".{$ext}";

        $path = Yii::$app->params['uploadPath'] . '/' . $new_name;
        $model->fm_upload = $new_name;

        $file->saveAs($path);

        if($model->save()){
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id'=>$model->_id]);

        } else {
            // error in saving model
        }
    }
```

Comment: Still same issue.

Actually I am not sure about the path, where is the default path, if I do ./uploads/, where is the base path?

Then, about the redirect, is that correct? The 'view' and 'id' part.

Comment: For upload path you can use alias like `@web` or `@webroot`.

Comment: @InsaneSkull so, something like @web/uploads/ ??

Comment: @Luqman Use `(Yii::getAlias('@web).'/uploads/'.$new_name`. it will store file under web/uploads.

Comment: @Luqman I've edited the answer, use a defined alias or custom one (if you need different folders)

Comment: @stig-js Actually I have used your edited answer awhile ago, but still no go. Is it because of my table? Do I need a new table for storing the file information? Currently everything is on 1 table, with only 1 column dedicated for the file path.

Comment: @Luqman No, the file info is in $file var, so try with $model->save(false) and check if the file is saved, so the problem is in validation rules.

Comment: @stig-js still not saving. :( I am out of ideas on where to look. been trying a few other tutorials too, including the official yii2 docs.

Comment: @stig-js I think that is one of the issue, and another one, I am not sure why, I have to put $model->save() above $file->saveAs($path); for it to be able to work. If not I will get error "cannot open file stream, file not found". I guess its needs to be save before redirecting it to the server path.

Anyway thank you thank you thank you! Accepted this answer!